# ActionBar with popup menu at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I wonder if it is possible to have a popup menu at the bottom of the screen additionally? I'd like this menu to appear when the user clicks the default menu button (hardware for older mobiles).

How can I do this?

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe you are talking about using a ContextMenu? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html

Comment: No, sorry. I'm thinking about menu that appears at the bottom after pressing menu button on older mobiles.

Comment: You want to show the options menu right ? which opens on press of the menu key in devices ?

Comment: Yeah, but i already done it using @Doctoror clue : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actionbar menu overflow is automatically replaced by items in "menu" popup if you have a hardware menu button.
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html

In order for items to appear in there you should set

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

to your menu items

Answer (score 1):

You must take a look at the [How to Create Android Menus?](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

I hope this will help you.